# styling bootstrap-vue dropdown button

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have this dropdown menu with bootstrap-vue in my nuxtjs app:

```
<div>
  <b-dropdown class="dropdown" id="dropdown-1" text="Dropdown Button" class="m-md-2">
    <b-dropdown-item>First Action</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item>Second Action</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item>Third Action</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-divider></b-dropdown-divider>
    <b-dropdown-item active>Active action</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item disabled>Disabled action</b-dropdown-item>
  </b-dropdown>
</div>
```

I want to be able to change the border and background color of my dropdown button through this code:

```
<style scoped>
  .dropdown {
    border: solid 0px;
    background: white;
  }
</style>
```

Please note that the style **MUST** be scoped. What am I doing wrong and how can I change style of my dropdown button?

Comment: Did you check in your browser to see which styles are being applied and from where?

Comment: Yes so on the browser there is a `<button>` child to `class="dropdown"` that has the styling and it can be modified through browser but I dunno how I can reach and modify it through my code!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`toggle-class`](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/dropdown#comp-ref-b-dropdown-props) to assign a scoped CSS class to your dropdown toggle button and `variant='none'` to disable the default variant in effect when the toggle button is clicked.

**Template**

```
<b-dropdown toggle-class='customDropdown' variant='none' class="m-md-2" id="dropdown-1" text="Dropdown Button">
  <b-dropdown-item>First Action</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item>Second Action</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item>Third Action</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-divider></b-dropdown-divider>
    <b-dropdown-item active>Active action</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item disabled>Disabled action</b-dropdown-item>
</b-dropdown>
```

**CSS**

```
<style scoped>
  .customDropdown {
    border: 3px dashed cyan;
    background-color: purple;
  }
</style>
```

**Sample result:**
[image]

Comment: Wonderful! You pointed me in the write direction: setting `variant='none'` was key for solving my (exact same) issue. In my case, I was also working with a `scoped` style: no need to go for the `toggle-class`, a simple `class` did the job perfectly.